# How can I get transactions from a wallet using alchemy websockets

Tags: javascript, blockchain, solidity, ethers.js, ws

I want to get all new transactions from a specified wallet and Im using this code. It just dont work when I use the function `tx["transaction"]["from"]` and I filter the wallet or ca I want on `"WALLET"`.

Im using Alchemy methods with ws and I have read the documentation about how to use it, I should be missing something.

```
const { Alchemy, Network, AlchemySubscription } = require("alchemy-sdk")
const {ethers, FixedNumber} = require("ethers")
const delay = require('delay')
require("dotenv").config()

const ARBI_WS_KEY = process.env.ARBI_WS_KEY

const settings = {
  apiKey: ARBI_WS_KEY, // Replace with your Alchemy API Key
  network: Network.ARB_MAINNET, // Replace with your network
}

const alchemy = new Alchemy(settings)

// Subscription for Alchemy's minedTransactions API
const add = async () => {
    alchemy.ws.on(
        {
            method: AlchemySubscription.MINED_TRANSACTIONS,
        },
        (tx) => {
            let add0 = String(tx["transaction"]["from"])

            if( add0 == "WALLET"){
                console.log(tx["transaction"]["hash"])
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Its weird because everything works when I filter `tx["transaction"]["to"]` and I specify a wallet or a contract to filter but when trying to filter `"from"` I dont get anything.

Answer (score 0):

here is the sample script to get transactions from the chain.

the data need to be filtered accordingly.

```
const  WSSURL_BSC= `Alchemylink`;
const { ethers } = require("ethers");
var provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider(WSSURL_BSC);
provider.on("block", (blockNumber) => {

    provider.getBlockWithTransactions(blockNumber).then(block => {
        console.log(`Got txns for block ${blockNumber}`);
        block.transactions.filter(tx => tx.data == '0x').forEach(tx => {
            // raw transactions
        });
        block.transactions.filter(tx => tx.data != '0x').forEach(tx => {
            // token transactions
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: ty, I was calling the contract with different case letters and that was the amin problem

Comment: That would be the reason, some chains consider checksum address and some consider lowercase address, so cross check before you move on selected chain